# Understanding $|\sum_{k\in S}z_k|\geq\frac{1}{\pi}\sum_{k=1}^{N}|z_k|$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I'm currently reading through Rudin's *Real and Complex Analysis (3rd Edition)* textbook and have stumbled upon a lemma which reads as follows:

> **6.3 Lemma** If $z_1,...,z_N$ are complex numbers then there is a subset $S$ of $\{1,...,N\}$ for which $|\sum_{k\in s}z_k|\geq\frac{1}{\pi}\sum_{k=1}^{N}|z_k|$. [c.f. pg. 118].

The proof is a lot to type out, so I hope the image at the bottom is sufficient. However, the proof isn't necessarily what's of concern to me, this part makes perfect sense. What I'm confused on is the intuitive aspect: How could one go about visualizing this statement? Or at the very least explain it in a manner which is less logically-sound, and more intuitively sound? It's a very useful lemma which I'm shocked to have found no other articles on this site discussing. If somebody could attempt to clarify what's going here, I would greatly appreciate it! Thank you.

---

[image]

Comment: Sorry for the nitpicking, would you mind changing $n$ to $N$? It's a very nice question!

Comment: *“I'm shocked to have found no other articles on this site discussing”* – What about https://math.stackexchange.com/q/967906/42969  and https://math.stackexchange.com/q/654840/42969 ?

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Fixed it. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: @MartinR This is certainly helpful, however I'm looking for an intuitive explanation as opposed to proofs. I'll nonetheless read through the alternate proofs you have provided to see if it makes any further intuitive sense, though I remain curious as to see what answers I can get on here.

Comment: Here is another one with one geometric proof (with a weaker constant): https://math.stackexchange.com/q/91939/42969

Comment: if you are happy with a worse constant than $1/\pi$ the explanation is simple - if complex numbers are within a controlled angle so all their real (or all ther imaginary) parts are comparable to their modulus, so in other words $\cos \arg w >=\delta$ (or similar) for all, the inequality is obvious and by the pigeonhole principle we can always find a fixed fraction like that by splitting the plane into a few sectors

Comment: And here is the generaliization to higher dimensions: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/102508/42969

Comment: @MartinR Great I'll look into these previously answered questions. Thank you!